# Sharepoint 2010 After runs install-spsolution continues deployed false on

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I try to deploy a webpart solution. I execute in sharepoint 2010 management shell all steps to upload and implement.

1. `add-spsolution c:\site\subwebs.wsp`. This execute wit out problem.
2. `install-spsolution -identity subwebs.wsp -webapplication http://sp2010 -gacdeployment -force`.
3. `Update-SPSolution –Identity SharePointProject2.wsp –LiteralPath c:site\subwebs.wsp –GACDeployment`

after review with get-spsolution the solution do not deployed.

```
name         Solutionid             Deployed
----         ----------             --------
subwebs      "id"                   false
```

I Review all events but don't find any errors.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In your step 2 you should not use -force as it means "if any error continue and don't show them"
Your Step 3 should not be executed as there is no need to upgrade to the same version which has just been deployed. This is only for when you get a new version.

So try to run the right step 2:

> install-spsolution -identity subwebs.wsp -webapplication http://sp2010 -gacdeployment

It might be a good idea to have ULS viewer running at the same time to see if anything is logged. I recommend using [this ULS viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) not the one from codeplex

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any error when you go to Solution Store?

What are the contents of your WSP file,  is there a feature which is not supported on a particular scope.

I am sure there must be some installation errors,  do review the ULS log.

Comment: No errors on solution. Where is located ULS logs?

Comment: its usually in the 14\Logs folder (unless you have specified a different location for logs)

Comment: you can download ULS Log Viewer from codeplex http://ulsviewer.codeplex.com/